# New NSNumber literals

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.5, nsnumber

Since there is new `NSNumber` literals in Objective-C that you can use, for instance:

```
NSNumber *n1 = @1000;  // [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000]
```

But it doesn't seem to be possible to use together with enums? I have tried:

```
typedef enum {

    MyEnumA = 0,
    MyEnumB,
    MyEnumC

} MyEnum;

NSNumber *n2 = @MyEnumA;  // [NSNumber numberWithInt:MyEnumA]
```

But I get a compiler error saying:

> Unexpected '@' in program

I don't understand why it doesn't work since an enum is an int?
Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For named constants, you need to use `@(MyEnumA)`.

Comment: The reason is that Apple might want to add a keyword called `@MyEnumA` later, and don't want to break your code.

Comment: @GrahamLee Name clashes are not restricted to future additions to the language. Consider an enum named `interface` or `end`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
NSNumber *n2 = @(MyEnumA);
```

I know it's odd, but it's just the way it is. I can't think off the top of my head but I assume the parser needs the parentheses in order to distinguish between different syntax.

What I tend to do is to use parentheses always. That works with normal numbers as well as enums as well as equations like:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;
NSNumber *n = @(a*b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained what the proper syntax is. Here's *why*:

`@blah` is called the "literal" syntax. You use it to make objects wrapping a literal, like a char, BOOL, int, etc. that means:

- `@42` is a boxed int
- `@'c'` is a boxed char
- `@"foo"` is a boxed char*
- `@42ull` is a boxed unsigned long long
- `@YES` is a boxed BOOL

All of the things following the at sign are primitive values. `MyEnumValue` is not a literal. It's a symbol. To accommodate this, generic boxing syntax was introduced:

```
@(MyEnumValue)
```

You can put a bunch of things inside the parentheses; for the most part, any sort of variable or expression ought to work.